# Migrating from linux shared server to Azure

Tags: linux, azure, migration, shared-hosting

I have 5 existing wordpress websites running on a linux shared hosting. The most acessed one has the maximum of 10000 page views/day and 500 page views/day on average. The others have few page views.

How can I migrate those existing websites to Azure, keeping cost and simplicity in mind?
Maybe creating a ubuntu server vm or centos server vm, but I never managed a linux server before.

Answer (score 1):

You can either run WordPress front-end web applications in Linux/Windows VMs or on [Azure App Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-web-site-gallery#launch-and-manage-your-wordpress-web-app) platform.

For the backend databases, you can install MySQL on the same VM, a separated VM, or use one of the PaaS services available. Microsoft just launched it's own [MySQL as a Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal) solution.

After you have built and configured your WordPress application in Azure, all you have to do is export and import the data within Wordpress control panel.

Said that it's hard to tell how much that would cost compared to your shared hosting services. I believe if what you are looking for is cost reduction, probably you won't get it in Azure because what it offers is dedicated scalable computing. Try to match what you currently get with your hosting provider in the [Azure Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/calculator/).